# pandas: label based on custom percentile for light tail data

Tags: python, pandas

Here's my data

```
ID      Score      
067628  1.860544    
067628  -1.779013   
010024  1.545405    
065166  1.331578
010024  -1.324276
...
010064  -0.324276 
...
```

The rules is

`+++` is for top 1 percent score

`++`  is for top 5 percent score, but not in top 1 percent score

`+`   is for top 15 percent score, but not in top 5 percent score

`---` is for bottom 1 percent score

`--`  is for bottom 5 percent score, but not in bottom 1 percent score

`-`   is for bottom 15 percent score, but not in bottom 5 percent score

`o`   is for the others

My expected output

```
ID      Score         Bucket        
067628  1.860544      +++
067628  -1.779013     ---
010024  1.545405      ++
065166  1.331578      ++
010024  -1.324276     --
...
010064  -0.324276     o
...
```

What I did is start with `df['bucket'] = pd.qcut(D['Score'], 100)`

but the result is

```
opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/tile.py in qcut(x, q, labels, retbins, precision, duplicates)
    358         quantiles = q
    359     bins = algos.quantile(x, quantiles)
--> 360     fac, bins = _bins_to_cuts(
    361         x,
    362         bins,

/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/tile.py in _bins_to_cuts(x, bins, right, labels, precision, include_lowest, dtype, duplicates, ordered)
    399     if len(unique_bins) < len(bins) and len(bins) != 2:
    400         if duplicates == "raise":
--> 401             raise ValueError(
    402                 f"Bin edges must be unique: {repr(bins)}.\n"
    403                 f"You can drop duplicate edges by setting the 'duplicates' kwarg"

ValueError: Bin edges must be unique: array([-1.77901317e+00, -3.01570505e-02, -2.17622392e-02, -1.83426444e-02,
       -1.54371076e-02, -1.36568587e-02, -1.09445204e-02, -9.26993391e-03,
       -8.59938687e-03, -6.99379123e-03, -5.43674054e-03, -4.37780817e-03,
       -3.72115545e-03, -2.95171802e-03, -1.99808604e-03, -1.63479767e-03,
       -1.41602779e-03, -1.41602669e-03, -5.44115527e-04, -4.00804938e-04,
       -2.94577878e-04, -7.75499803e-05,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,
        0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,
        0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,
        0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,
        0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,
        0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,
        0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,
        0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,
        0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,
        0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,
        0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,
        0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,
        0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,
        0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,
        0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,
        3.27429056e-17,  1.33788840e-06,  1.47122731e-04,  6.80741674e-04,
        7.85538913e-04,  1.44355690e-03,  1.53673750e-03,  2.20893269e-03,
        2.53860460e-03,  3.96656969e-03,  5.55582146e-03,  6.80561574e-03,
        9.07804112e-03,  1.10207579e-02,  1.19932632e-02,  1.45923859e-02,
        1.53351503e-02,  1.73507376e-02,  3.75900780e-02,  5.06678040e-02,
        1.86054406e+00]).
You can drop duplicate edges by setting the 'duplicates' kwarg
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`.qcut()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.qcut.html) defining with array of quantiles and labels corresponding to your criteria, as follows:

```
df['Bucket'] = pd.qcut(df['Score'], [0, 0.01, 0.05, 0.15, 0.85, 0.95, 0.99, 1], labels=["---", "--", "-", "o", '+', '++', '+++'])
```

Result:

```
print(df)


      ID     Score Bucket
0  67628  1.860544    +++
1  67628 -1.779013    ---
2  10024  1.545405      o
3  65166  1.331578      o
4  10024 -1.324276      o
5  10064 -0.324276      o
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible solution:

```
perc = [0.0, 0.01, 0.05, 0.15, 0.85, 0.95, 0.99, 1.0]
symb = ['---', '--', '-', 'o', '+', '++', '+++']

df['Bucket'] = None

for i, s in enumerate(symb):
    df.loc[(df['Score'] >= df['Score'].quantile(perc[i]))
           & (df['Score'] <= df['Score'].quantile(perc[i + 1])), 'Bucket'] = s
```